# Exceptions and TDetail

Tags: c#, exception

Here's what I need to do:

```
catch (System.ServiceModel.FaultException<CustomFault> ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

The problem is, the fault I'm getting is

```
System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException
```

How do I return the custom fault?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to catch the fault server-side? That's not going to work; `MessageSecurityException` is thrown before server code gets executed.

If you're trying to catch the fault in client-side code, just use

```
catch (System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException ex)
{
    // handle exception
}
```

Comment: The custom fault returns information that is not in the exception (ex).  How do I get that data?

Comment: @divided: I need more context before I can answer that. If the fault is not actually what's generating the exception, then you *can't* get the information you require. If you're getting `MessageSecurityException` client-side, odds are your binding is wrong.

Comment: @divided: then you are not communicating with the service. The exception is being thrown while attempting to establish communications. I would inspect the actual error message of that exception to determine what the cause is. Odds are you're not supplying valid authentication credentials to the service. But that's just a guess. Only the actual exception can help point you in the right direction.

Comment: Well the inner fault exception that I'm getting is a 'legitimate' error from the web service, so, I'm able to hit it.

Comment: @divided: that doesn't really say much, though, does it? You're able to do some communications, but something in the security of the messages you're trying to send is failing. Check the error message and recheck your bindings